# An alternative to a (huge) nested loop (inner join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance

Please have a look at this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
    b.player_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.team = m.team_win THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.team <> m.team_win THEN 1 END)
FROM
    players a,
    players b,
JOIN
    matches m
    ON m.match_id = b.match_id
WHERE
    a.player_id <> b.player_id
    and a.team <> b.team
    and a.player_id = 100
GROUP BY
    b.player_id
```

Upon completion, the statement should present a recordset whose columns are:

- The `b.player_id` which `a.player_id` played against.
- The `count` of matches where `a.player_id` defeated `b.player_id`.
- The `count` of matches where `a.player_id` was defeated by `b.player_id`.

Unfortunately, these tables are quite large. `matches` is about 1.6 million rows. `players` is about 17 million rows, so joining them is presenting some challenges:

The execution plan index seeks both tables `players` and `matches`, then emits a `nested loop (inner join)`, a step with **1,176,730,000,000** estimated rows.

Other misc. information:

`player_id` is `tinyint`, `team` is `bit`, `team_win` is `bit`.

`match_id` is `bigint primary key` with a foreign key constraint on `players`

**Matches Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Matches](
    [match_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [match_seq_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [team_win] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Matches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [match_id] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Players Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players] (
    [id]         [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [match_id]   [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [account_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [team]       [bit] NOT NULL,
    [player_id]  [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    /* column list has been truncated for brevity. */
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Players] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [id] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Players] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Players_Matches] FOREIGN KEY([match_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Matches] ([match_id])
```

Comment: Your query is not doing what you think it is doing.  Please provide the layout of the `players` and `matches` tables.  Why, for instance, would a table called `players` have a `matchid` in it?

Comment: You have a cartesian product...joining players a on players b where a.playerID <> b.playerID is creating 17 million - 1 * 17 million - 1 rows....that can't be intentional, can it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Added the tables. Think of Players as, more like, "Players that participated in a particular match." There's roughly 10, give or take, for every `match_id` in Matches.

Comment: @Twelfth: That's the only way I could think to get the result set that I desire. If there's a better way (and I'm positive there must be) then I shall need to learn it.

Comment: sorry, read the above comment to gordon.   So this is supposed to be a win / loss count for each player?

Comment: @Twelfth: For each match played by one or more humans, a row is added to Matches. For each human that participated in that match, a row is added to Players. If a human participates in multiple matches, then they have a row in Players for each Match that they participated in. `match_id` is the foreign key that links them together.

Comment: @Twelfth: Yes, it should be able to determine that player_id 'X' wins/losses a certain amount versus player_id 'Y'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a join to the `players` table, so you're getting a cartesian product. Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    b.player_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.team = m.team_win THEN 0 END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.team <> m.team_win THEN 1 END)
FROM
    matches m
JOIN players a ON m.match_id = a.match_id
JOIN players b ON m.match_id = b.match_id
WHERE
    a.player_id <> b.player_id
    and a.team <> b.team
    and a.player_id = 100
GROUP BY
    b.player_id
```

Comment: +1 looks right...he needed to start at the matches table, not at player.

Comment: You turned a *trillion* row nested loop in to a fraction of a second query. Thank you. Wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: @JHallam - Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to know:  For each player, how many times did that players team win and how many did they lose, when the player played against 100.  Let's get the team summary first:

```
SELECT p.team,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.team = m.team_win THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as teamwins,
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.team <> m.team_win THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as teamlosts
FROM players p JOIN
     matches m
     ON m.match_id = p.match_id
GROUP BY p.team
HAVING sum(case when p.player_id = 100 then 1 else 0 end) -- be sure player 100 played
```

Next, you can join back to the players to get the team information.

I'm stopping here for now because I need to be sure that the teams are stable over time.